# append td with width value from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an array as follow and I like them to be the width of `<td>` that I like to append.

```
<table>
  <tr class="table_row">
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
var arr = [40, 60, 80, 100]
var table_row = $('.table_row');
for(var i=0; i<arr.length  i++){
  table_row.append('<td style="width:arr[i]></td>')
}
</script>
```

I think I need  to concatenate the `arr[i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a semicolon in your `for`:

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length  i++){
//-----------------------^ here
```

Also when you define your `td` to append:

```
table_row.append('<td style="width:arr[i]"></td>');
```

You are putting the text `arr[i]` instead of the array value. The `width` unit is also missing which you can set as `px` for example.

To fix the array value issue you can either concatenate:

```
table_row.append('<td style="width:' + arr[i] + '"></td>');
```

Or use [String interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
table_row.append(`<td style="width:${arr[i]}"></td>`);
```

Note that with interpolation the outter ticks were changed from ' to `.

Fixing everything:

```js
var arr = [40, 60, 80, 100];
var table_row = $('.table_row');
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  table_row.append(`<td style="width:${arr[i]}px;">&nbsp;</td>`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr class="table_row">
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that i added a `&nbsp;` in the `td`s and a `border` in the `table` so that you can better see the result in the live snippet

Comment: @DylanHsiao No problem. Best of luck for the rest of the development.

Comment: Thank you. I am really new to Javascript and everything, it really helps me to read more documentation and stuff! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr class="table_row">
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
var arr = [40, 60, 80, 100];
var table_row = $('.table_row');
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  table_row.append(`<td style="width:${arr[i]}px;"></td>`)
}
</script>
```

Try to use this.